# Windows forms CheckedListBox issue

Tags: vb.net, winforms, checkedlistbox

I am working on a desktop application developed in vb.net. I am trying to select the items in a checkedlistbox depending on the values I get from database. Below is the code to populate the checkedlistboxes

```
Private Sub LoadDisapprovalList()

    cblFedralReasons.Items.Clear()
    cblStateReasons.Items.Clear()

    cblFedralReasons.DataSource = Main.DataClient.DisapprovalReasonList_Get(FedralReason)
    cblFedralReasons.DisplayMember = "DisapprovalReasonTypeDesc"
    cblFedralReasons.ValueMember = "DisapprovalReasonTypeGenId"

    cblStateReasons.DataSource = Main.DataClient.DisapprovalReasonList_Get(StateReason)
    cblStateReasons.DisplayMember = "DisapprovalReasonTypeDesc"
    cblStateReasons.ValueMember = "DisapprovalReasonTypeGenId"

End Sub
```

After that I am trying to select the items based on the values from database. Here is the code

```
    Private Sub LoadApplicationDisapprovalReasons()
    Dim lstApplicationDisapprovalReasons As New List(Of DataService.usp_ApplicationDisapprovalReason_Get_Result)
    lstApplicationDisapprovalReasons = Main.DataClient.ApplicationDisapprovalReason_Get(_SeqID)

    If lstApplicationDisapprovalReasons.Count > 0 Then

        For Each item In lstApplicationDisapprovalReasons

            Dim selectedDisapprovalId As Integer = item.DisapprovalReasonTypeGenId
            Select Case item.DisapprovalReasonType
                Case FedralReason    
                    Dim selectedIndex = cblFedralReasons.Items.IndexOf(selectedDisapprovalId)
                    cblFedralReasons.SetItemCheckState(selectedIndex, CheckState.Checked)

                Case StateReason

                    Dim selectedIndex = cblStateReasons.Items.IndexOf(selectedDisapprovalId)
                    cblStateReasons.SetItemCheckState(selectedIndex, CheckState.Checked)

            End Select

        Next

    End If

End Sub
```

But the problem is cblFedralReasons.Items.IndexOf always returns -1. All the data from database is coming correctly but something weird happening with checkedlistbox which I couldn't understand.

EDIT:
Also when I try to get the text of an item by using the following code it returns me name of my collections instead of the text.

```
cblFedralReasons.items(1).tostring
```

It returns

```
DisapprovalReasonList
```

and not the text of that item!

Comment: Sounds like the CLB is working with a different set of objects than are in the list.  What does `DisapprovalReasonList_Get` return (the exact Type)?  ToString will return the Type name unless the class overrides it.

Comment: That is a list of type  List(Of  DataService.usp_DisapprovalReasonList_Get)

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to explain what I think about this:

If *cblFedralReasons* has as Datasource a *List(Of DataService.usp_DisapprovalReasonList)*, if you search a *selectedDisapprovalId* vía *IndexOf* passing an Integer on the list.... that -1 value returned, its coherent.
*IndexOf*, on a collection, are internally doing a *Equals* comparison. So you are comparing different types: an *Integer* vs a *DataService.usp_DisapprovalReasonList*.

**There are many ways to get the correct object from the collection.**

**One idea** could be do an override of object.equals in your class:

```
Public Overrides Function Equals(ByVal p_oAnotherObject As Object) As Boolean 
    If TypeOf p_oAnotherObject Is DataService.usp_DisapprovalReasonList AndAlso Me.GetType.Equals(p_oAnotherObject.GetType) Then
        Return Me.DisapprovalReasonTypeGenId.Equals(DirectCast(p_oAnotherObject, DataService.usp_DisapprovalReasonList).DisapprovalReasonTypeGenId)
    Else
        Return False
    End If
End Function
```

Assuming you have a constructor accepting an ID, you now can do this:

```
cblFedralReasons.Items.IndexOf(New DataService.usp_DisapprovalReasonList(selectedDisapprovalId))
```

and then, you will get it.

Finally, cblFedralReasons.items(1).tostring, you are getting the default GetType.Name. Do this in your class, then:

```
Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
    Return DisapprovalReasonTypeDesc
End Function
```

Hope I have explained.